# Why does no drift factor in a stochastic differential equation imply that the process is a Martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I was working on this problem:

Use Itô's formula to prove that the following stochastic processes
are martingales:

$$ \begin{equation}
    \bullet \quad  X_t = e^\frac{t}{2}\cos B_t \\
    \bullet \quad  X_t = e^\frac{t}{2}\sin B_t \\
    \bullet \quad  X_t = (B_t + t)e^{-B_t - \frac{t}{2}} \\
\end{equation}$$

I used Ito's lemma to prove that the resulting stochastic differential equation is independent of any drift factor. How does it imply that $X_t$ is a martingale, mathematically. How can you prove it?

$$ \begin{equation}
\bullet \quad dX_t = -e^\frac{t}{2}\sin B_t dB_t \\
\bullet \quad dX_t = e^\frac{t}{2}\cos B_t dB_t \\
\bullet \quad dX_t = e^{-B_t - \frac{t}{2}}(1 - B_t -t)dB_t \\
\end{equation}$$

These are the resulting differential equations, all independent of drift. How can you prove, in general, that an SDE independent of drift, is a Martingale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in general because $dB_t$ is independent of $B_t$ by the definition of the Wiener process/Brownian motion. More specifically, for the unbound parts of the path in the future of time point $s$, $t\ge s$ 
$\newcommand{\IE}{\Bbb E}$
$$
\IE_s(f(t,B_t)dB_t)=\IE_s(f(t,B_t))\IE_s(dB_t)=0
$$
which taken together with the fixed parts of the path under $\cal F_s$ in the past of time point $s$ implies
$$
\IE_s(X_t-X_0)=\IE_s\left(\int_0^t f(u,B_u)dB_u\right)=\int_0^s f(u,B_u)dB_u=X_s-X_0.
$$
This is the main property defining a martingale.

Comment: how does the penultimate equality hold? you just proved on the previous line that that conditional expectation should be $= 0$, didn't you? Could you also add something on "$dB_t$ is independent on $B_t$" and also why $E[dB_t|\mathcal F_s]=0$? i agree that $E[dB_t]=0$ but why also the conditional expectation?

Comment: The expectation for past events, $u<s$, is of course the actual value of these past events, "the probability wave has already collapsed".

Comment: yes, but it seemed to me that was contradictory with the firs equation, where you proved that it was instead $=0$ (here: $\Bbb E_s(f(t,B_t)dB_t)=\Bbb E_s(f(t,B_t))\Bbb E_s(dB_t)=0$). And then, why is equal to 0?

Comment: No, it is not a contradiction as the first equation concerns the uncertain future $t\ge s$ and not the certain past.